# What is this feed though attachment in my home Load Panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I am looking to upgrade my outdoor main panel to a Square D QO panel. However, this outdoor 200A load center feeds my indoor 200A load center, and it does so not by using any of the breaker spaces but instead the bolt on piece at the bottom.

What is this called, and are they made for Square D QO panels such that I could upgrade it?

The part I'm asking about is in the dashed red rectangle. It passes the full current on the bus bar to the indoor panel.

[image: Outdoor Load Center]

### Edit

There seems to be some questions about the neutral/ground bonding in this main panel, it is indeed bonded behind the main breaker in this panel. The Meter neutral comes in on the left, the sub panel is getting its neutral (insulated white) and ground (twisted aluminum) bonded on the right. This all checks out to me, so perhaps this diagram helps clear the situation up?

[image: Ground Wiring]

Comment: I don't think that panel is right- there's no connection between the two bus bars. The neutral from the meter comes in and is attached to the left side, whereas the neutral for the house is fed off the right. I see a ground wire on the left to the box, but not that appears to be entering the ground.

Comment: @J.Hirsch  I agree with you (see my comment in the answer part).  Unless there is a conductor hidden behind the plastic part that goes behind the breaker, this looks like all the neutral currents are going thru the ground connections.   Not good!

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson There is indeed a conductor behind the black plastic behind the main panel breaker, between neutral and ground. Does that address the issue?

Comment: @Ehryk ...Maybe. Normally, what I'd expect to see (and I am NOT a Master electrician or familiar with your local codes) is that all those neutrals are tied together, all the ground are tied together, the box is grounded at the ground lug- and most importantly the strap (that goes between the two bus bars) are intact. For a 2nd panel however that strap has to be broken (which would be your main panel) because that counts as a sub panel. So... I'm not really sure.

Comment: @J.Hirsch Seem my 2nd picture in my latest edit. This is my main panel, so the strap is present. On the panel indoors, as a sub panel, it has a separate Ground and Neutral coming into this panel. This meets your expectations then, right?

Comment: @Ehryk YES!. If the inside panel is split properly (ground bus, neutral bus), and the strap bonding those two are broken- AND the grounding screw is only present on the ground bus bar, then yes- that's all correct. I'm sorry for worrying you unnecessarily; I've just heard (and seen) some bad things. Thank you for taking the time to allay my fear.

Comment: @J.Hirsch I do plan on making sure there are no remaining ground <-> neutral connections on my indoor panel and none of the grounds are going to the neutral bar, it might be possible as that used to be the main panel before this was put in, but it does look like they did everything right and for sure there is no strap like the one shown here. The ground is tied to the metal casing, which is also good, so to the best of my knowledge everything appears right in there as well. I'm glad I could allay your fears (this is my first home and I'm still learning).

Comment: Just like anything electrical, @Ehryk, check with your local code enforcement office to get it inspected. They get final sign off and will ensure there's no 'gotchas' that no one on the 'net could figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is call a FEED THROUGH LUG and it's used for exactly what you have.  Feeding from one panel to the next.

Yes, they seem to be available for SOME Square D QO panels but you'll need to check by the model number.

Comment: I would also suggest comparing the price of the feed through lug kit to that of a 200A breaker, you could then use the breaker to feed the next panel. Not required, but a nice convenience (can de-energeize downstream panel by shutting off breaker, but retain power to main panel). If it's only marginally more expensive, that may be a good option and give you more panel choices as well.

Comment: Good point.  I'd have assumed that one of these feed through lug kits would be less expensive than a 200A breaker but it appears that is not the case.  At least not for feed through lugs that are not pre-installed.

Comment: Square D has some "interesting" pricing strategies.

Comment: When I built my house I wanted a SquareD QO pass thru panel and they were not available at that time.  Oddly enough a SquareD Homeline pass thru panel was available, but I don't like Homeline.  

Why do you wish to upgrade the outdoor panel?

Maybe one of the "big three" could weigh in here, but doesn't it appear that the neutral on the left side of the box is wholly inadequately connected to the neutral/ground bussbar on the right?  Or is there a conductor hidden behind the plastic part the runs behind the main breaker?

Comment: You may be able to find an electrical contractor/supply house that will assemble the panel cheaper. I did so with breaker swap outs, cost me nothing extra (I also was buying 40 breakers)

Comment: @PhilippNagel Great suggestion! I'm seeing $195 on eBay and $275 on Amazon for the QO2200. Do I need to check panel compatibility or would that work with any QO panel in any position?

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson I want to upgrade because I like the red 'blown' indicator on the QO breakers, I want to add a Square D while house surge protector while I'm wiring in my solar circuit, and even though I can put Homeline breakers in that panel I think it's against code to do so.

Comment: @J.Hirsch What is a contractor supply house (as in what would I search for in Google Maps to find one)? And would anyone really swap old Challenger parts for Square D QO parts???

Comment: @Ehryk when I said swap, I should have said "bought one thing, they swapped in replacements". I actually found a bunch of places that had businesses online and was able to purchase there (got one through ebay, of all places). Searching for "Electrical Supply House" should do it. Looking on Craigslist too as everyone (now) is trying to make a buck to survive, and inventory is useless if it isn't sold.

Comment: @jwh20 What I'm now noticing is that the lugs are not 'bolt on' to any regular panel interiors, they are their own separate interior. So to get Feed Though Lugs on a QO panel, I would have to order the specific panel with the FTLs, not a panel and a separate FTL kit to bolt in. I guess that answers my question then - you don't buy the lugs to retrofit a panel, you buy a panel with them. I think I'll be going the 200A breaker route with a QO2200 breaker feeding the sub panel, so I can have more panel options.

Comment: @Ehryk Yeah -- the most common QO FTL panel (and the most direct replacement for what you have) is the QO1816M200FTRB.  (There is a larger feed-through-lug panel floating about the QO catalog, namely the QO12436L200TFT, but it's a bit of a unicorn on a good day, and also not available in NEMA 3R to begin with...)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yeah, the QO1816M200FTRB doesn't have enough spaces for me (I've got uses for 16, but I don't want to put it in and use every space) so I'm going to put in a 30 space panel and use 4 up for a QO2200, leaving 10 empty when everything is in (I'm going to add solar, 2xEV charging, and a 220 for a welder to the existing slots). Also the QO130M200PRB is $252 at Home Depot. Are there any reasons I'm unaware of that would make that not a good replacement setup?

Comment: @Ehryk -- I'd look at pricing on something in the 40-42 space range if a 30-space is that much...the marginal costs are going to be low if not nonexistent

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Am I missing something on pricing? There's a 42 Space Outdoor QO Plug on Neutral 200A panel for $253 (QO142M200PCVP), but I prefer the way the 30 Space opens (big flat panel that opens with a hinge at the top) over the 42 (window that opens with a hinge on the side). $244 for the 30 Space Outdoor Plug on Neutral 200A (QO130M200PRB) is the best price I can find - I realize I'm paying a premium for QO and Plug on Neutral. Is there something else I'm missing, or is the general reaction to Square D pricing?

Comment: @Ehryk QO is a premium (commercial/light-industrial-grade) product line that commands a premium price (if you put "Square-D" and "Cheap" together, you get Homeline).  Anyway, given that you have a panel inside, 26 spaces (after you count the QO2200 out) isn't too bad for an outside panel

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Right, so that price is fairly expected for that specific panel? Like I said I'll only use 16 slots (with the QO2200), so 14 extra will be more than plenty for any future expansion I haven't considered. I'm still a bit overwhelmed in trying to get this figured out, but I think the QO130M200PRB with a QO2200 is the best fit for what I want (Square D, QO, Plug on Neutral, at least 20 spaces, Outdoor, flat panel cover), so I'm in $439 + other breakers.

Comment: @Ehryk -- yeah, given that you want the top hinged box, you're best off with what you picked